# Eclipse: How to include dependencies in osgi bundle export?

Tags: maven, osgi, websphere-liberty, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

Using Eclipse, I have a (sort of) working OSGI bundle. It uses Maven to pull a lot of dependencies.

If I do right-click > Run As "Maven Build" and select the "package" as the goal, I end up with a jar with all my dependencies (good), but if I do "Export > OSGI Bundle" the dependencies are missing.

The issue is that I have another project (WebSphere Liberty Feature Project) that includes the bundle, but when it pulls it, it is also missing dependencies, so the resulting .esa file also misses the dependencies.

Is there a way to have eclipse process the dependencies so I don't have to manually package it outside eclipse or write a maven project exclusively for the purpose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue when I came across your post.
I assumed that the jars would be included in the exported jar and be found at runtime.

Originally, I had created a seperate "lib" directory and added the libraries to it, but they would not be included when exporting either as Bundle export or Liberty feature export (ESA)

I solved the problem first be using the "Java Archive into OSGi Bundle" import wizard.

You can select a jar dependency and add it to you bundle of your choice with the wizard. What I noticed when I used this, is that the jars were added to the "BundleContent" folder in the chosen bundle.

As I had a number of libraries to include, I simply moved them all to the "BundleContent" folder, updated the build time and runtime classpaths and then when exporting, the dependencies were all included and at runtime, the classes could then be found when they previously were not.

Answer (score 0):

In your POM, have you used [maven-bundle-plugin](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) and its [usage-details](http://felix.apache.org/components/bundle-plugin/bundle-mojo.html) for creating a bundle. If not, you can use it to define creation of your bundle and can also define dependencies to be embedded when the bundle is created.